# Problema al leer un archivo xml con mi app

Tags: android, android-studio, xml

Desde hace varios años uso un código que encontré en internet para leer el rss de mi web y mostrar la info en mi app. Pues ahora intento hacer algo muy parecido con otra app pero me está dando problemas.

Cree un archivo xml copiando la estructura de uno proveniente del rss de mi web. Lo subí al servidor y funcionó. Pero ahora agregué más contenido, incluyendo más etiquetas, las cuales nombre de cualquier forma (me pareció leer que eso sí se puede hacer). En fin, cuando abro mi app para que lea ese archivo, hago que imprima los tags en el Logcat de Android Studio, pero por un tiempo me muestra los tags anteriores. Es como si tardara un tiempo, esto respresenta un problema, porque necesito que la app vea cualquier cambio que haga en el archivo xml inmediatamente. ¿Hay alguna manera de solucionar esto?

Lo otro es que si utilizo tags personalizados, entonces la app no los ve. Aquí no puedo explicar si es por la cuestión del tiempo o realmente estoy usando mal las etiquetas.

Aquyí les dejo algunos ejemplos de tags que he utilizado: <aviso-T'> <sorteos'> <version'> <habitos'> (tuve que poner la comilla simple para que se visualizaran aquí).

Les dejo el código donde hago el parseo (está algo enredado porque tomé el original y lo modifiqué a mi manera):

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public void parse() {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document dom = builder.parse(this.url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList itema = root.getElementsByTagName("item");
        
            Node item = itema.item(0);
            NodeList properties = item.getChildNodes();
            for (int j = 0; j < properties.getLength(); j++) {
                Node property = properties.item(j);
                String name = property.getNodeName();
                Log.i("ETIQUETAS", name);

                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("version")) {
                    MyBus.setVersion(property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                }

                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("avisoT")) {
                    MyBus.setTituloAviso(property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                }

                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("avisoM")) {
                    MyBus.setContenidoAviso(property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                }

                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("sorteos")) {
                    int star = (property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().indexOf("<table class=\"tg0\">"));
                    int fiinal = (property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().indexOf("</table>"));
                    String cadena = (property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().substring(star, star+fiinal+8));
                    MyBus.setDomincal(cadena);

                    star = (property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().indexOf("<table class=\"tg1\">"));
                    String parteCadena = (property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().substring(star));
                    fiinal = parteCadena.indexOf("</table>");
                    cadena = (property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().substring(star, star+fiinal+8));
                    MyBus.setIntermedio(cadena);

                    star = (property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().indexOf("<table class=\"tg2\">"));
                    parteCadena = (property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().substring(star));
                    fiinal = parteCadena.indexOf("</table>");
                    cadena = (property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().substring(star, star+fiinal+8));
                    MyBus.setZodiacal(cadena);

                    star = (property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().indexOf("<table class=\"tg3\">"));
                    parteCadena = (property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().substring(star));
                    fiinal = parteCadena.indexOf("</table>");
                    cadena = (property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().substring(star, star+fiinal+8));
                    MyBus.setExtraordinario(cadena);

                }
            }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        
    }
}
```

Añado el principio de mi archivo xml (tomé de base uno del rss de mi página web en wordpress):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss version="2.0"
xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"

xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss"
xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#"
>
```

También añado un pedazo de dos de mis etiquetas, que básicamente tienen código html:

```
<habitos>
    <![CDATA[
        <table class="tg0">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th class="titulo" colspan="3">Hábitos más comunes</th>
        </tr>
        ...
        ...
        ...
</habitos>
```

Y aquí otra:

```
<avisot>Aviso Importante</avisot>
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Podrias colocar las dos primeras lineas del archivo xml? y un fragmento de las lineas de tus etiquetas personalizadas? Aunque tengo  un vago recuerdo ( los canales rss ya es algo bastante antiguo) que el rss , atom, xslt, etc. son  lenguajes escritos con xml , pero que deben tener un forma o formato estandar,  no lo recuerdo muy bien pero lo unico que podias hacer para meter informacion "extra" en los rss es colocar unas etiquetas predefinidas y estandares del "lenguaje", creo que no era posible inventarse etiquetas , por eso no te las reconoce

Comment: Ya añadí lo que me pediste. Dices que no puedo utilizar etiquetas personalizadas, pero he visto que al buscar info en youtube de leer un archivo xml en una app, al crear dichos archivos, ellos ponen etiquetas personalizadas. Quizás yo me esté confundiendo, investigaré más a fondo. Gracias por contestar.

Comment: @iqanansoft No, solo hay un item y dicho item es el que tiene varias etiquetas. Déjame probar con lo que dices del salto de línea, pero como dije anteriormente, en el Logcat me muestra etiquetas viejas (a veces hago pruebas cambiándolas a ver si ese es el problema).

Comment: Esa es otra etiqueta, que a veces me funciona y a veces no. Pero ya hice ciertas pruebas y al perecer tenías razón. Dentro de las etiquetas elimine los saltos de línea y algunos espacios y me funcionó casi todo bien. También eliminé las etiquetas personalizadas y utilice las que ya habían allí (title, link, etc.) y al parecer ya me funciona.

Comment: Lo que sí pude notar es que tengo que esperar bastante tiempo para que se reflejen los cambios. Eso no debería pasar pero aquí sí no sé de quién es el problema, aunque dudo que sea del servidor o de algo en el sitio web porque al revisar los cambios en el navegador sí se ven, pero en la app no, ni en el Logcat de Android Studio. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto? Es importante que se reflejen los cambios de manera inmediata.

Comment: he borrado tos mis comentarios y los he resumido en la respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escribo aqui la solución definitiva.....

Habia varios problemas que los solucionó Jhonny L testeando el codigo del archivo xml del rss

El primero era que la etiqueta de encabezamiento del xml y del item  por estandarización deben estar separados por un salto de linea

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0"
xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss"
xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#"
>
.......
```

El segundo problema, era que el rss sigue unas normas estándares, como por ejemplo que solo se pueden utilizar etiquetas predefinidas, y no permite el uso de otras etiquetas personalizadas.

Por cierto Jhonny L estos atributos o "namespace",  no te hacen falta si no vas a utilizar el estandar geoRSS y Atom

```
 xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
 xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss"
 xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#"
```

Comment: Bueno, falta añadir que dentro de la etiqueta 'habitos' (que ya no es más 'habitos'), hay un salto de línea justo al principio y otro después '<![CDATA[', pues esos los eliminé también. Y lo otro es que aún no resuelvo lo de la demora en actualizar los datos, pero creo que es cosa del mismo servidor.

Comment: el codigo que utilizas no influye en la demora, , eso dependera tambien de la cantidad de items que tenga  que analizar tu codigo en una misma ejecucion , no es lo mismo  que en una misma ejecucion analice 2 items que 200 items